# How to load specific data from JSON and show UICollection View?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uicollectionview, swifty-json

I am developing an app which is loading information from a JSON file and I use SwiftyJSON. Does someone of you know how can I populate only 8 records this information into a UI Collection View Cells?
My JSON has 50 records so my question is how can I populate only 8 records inside my UI Collection View Cells?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you can show 8 objects in `UICollectionView` by returning 8 with `numberOfItemsInSection` always. Check below code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if yourTableArr.count >= 8 {

        return 8
    } else {
        return yourTableArr.count
    }
}
```